# Delete rows where the difference between two columns is > 1

Tags: python, pandas

Update:
i have a table with coordinates of a point (x,y) and value of that point.
I have too many points, so i need to delete some of them and leave those with the highest value in specific area.
i am deleting only when x and y from one row is equal to x and y to another row.
Lets set the position limit =1, below 1 i want to filter points.

INPUT:

```
x , y ,value
1 , 1 , 12
2 , 2 , 11
4 , 2 , 22
5 , 5 , 78
6 , 6 , 33
```

i want on the output after =1 limit distance, leave the highest values:

RESULT I WANT TO RECEIVE:

```
x , y ,value
1 , 1 , 12
4 , 2 , 22
5 , 5 , 78
```

This code

```
df2 = df.loc[abs(df['x'] - df['y']) > 1]
df2.loc[df2['value'] == df2['value'].max()]
```

Gives me same result as:

```
df=df2.groupby(['x'])['value'].transform(max)== df2['value']
df3=df2[df]
```

but it still doesnt work;/
Thanks for help!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: df=df.loc[(df['X']>0)&(df['Y']>b),:] , but i haveonly more than 0 values and its not taking into account VALUE;/ i cant add option more less 0.1 in place where i have 0 . And also df.groupby, but i dont know how to put there this 0.1 difference for columns

Comment: Tried to clarify based on coherent information in the description and the expected output.

Comment: I don't understand why you are keeping both the row with `5,5,78` and the row with `1,1,12`. Didn't you say that you only want to keep the one with the highest value when the absolute difference between x and y is the same? So `1,1,12` should also be deleted? Also, please try to format your code block correctly (hint there is a button for it in the edit toolbar that looks like this `{}`). Look at my previous edit to the question and the guidelines http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.

Comment: @cheflo, thanks for the hint, this second table is my result i want to achive.

Comment: ok, so when you say "= 1 limit distance", do you mean `abs(x-y) <= 1`? If not, please show me the calculation that would give you the "distance" you are referring to, so that I understand better. After that, I can help you filter on the the value also.

Comment: @cheflo , the limit distance in case of two dimensions x and y its working 1>= and 1<= . lets imagine area with the points ( X Y area) and the distance is a radius of the circle. So now lets say the radius =1, and i need to delete all points in range of this radius, but leaves only the highest values of the point in this "radius area".

Comment: So if `x = 2` and `y = 4`, what is the "distance"? What would be the formula to calculate it?

Comment: @cheflo  x and y is not a distance, is a position in two dimensions area. (X,Y). Distance in this example is =1.

Comment: Yes, but how do you calculate a distance from just one point (x,y)? Do you mean its distance to the origin (0,0)?

Comment: @cheflo ,sorry now i think i understand Your question. distance = 1 from each point . so for point (5,5) distance =1 have in range each point to:(4-6, 4-6), so` delete point IF  IN RANGE [ (from x-1 to x+1) and (from y-1 to y+1)]  if value is lower`

Comment: I see, I think I get it now. You want to loop over all rows and compare the x,y coordinates of the current row to all other rows for (x+-1, y+-1). I posted a new answer below, try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the prettiest, but based on your latest comments on the question, I think this will get you what you want.

```
def dist_value_comp(row):                         
    x_dist = abs(df['y'] - row['y']) <= 1
    y_dist = abs(df['x'] - row['x']) <= 1
    xy_dist = x_dist & y_dist
    max_value = df.loc[xy_dist, 'value'].max()
    return row['value'] == max_value

df['keep_row'] = df.apply(dist_value_comp, axis=1)
df.loc[df['keep_row'], ['x', 'y', 'value']]
```

It works correctly with your sample data set from the question.

Comment: Thank You Bro, and sorry for misunderstandings . I will check it !

Comment: @Pawe was this answer helpful for you? If so, consider upvoting and accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding, but I don't think what you write corresponds to your expected output. Based on my interpretation, it seems like you want to eliminate rows with < 1 absolute difference between columns `x` and `y`. If this is correct, try

```
df.loc[abs(df['x'] - df['y']) > 1]
```

Feel free to rollback my edit to your question if you don't think it reflects what you are trying to achieve.

---

#### Update based on comments

I am still not sure I understand, but try

```
df2 = df.loc[abs(df['x'] - df['y']) > 1]
df2.loc[df2['value'] == df2['value'].max()]
```

or

```
df2 = df.loc[abs(df['x'] - df['y']) <= 1]
df.loc[(abs(df['x'] - df['y']) > 1) | (df['value'] == df2['value'].max())]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i need 0.1 not 1 i did a mistake but it makes no difference. Please take a look on my example table with results above. Lets say x and y are coordinates of the points and i need to delete each point near another one with radius 0.1 , but i need take into account the "value" and leaves only the highest one in that range. i have found something like this, but its not taking into account "value" the 3rd column;/ 
<code>from math import sqrt
def get_ordered_list(points, x, y):
  points.sort(key = lambda p: sqrt((p.x - x)**2 + (p.y - y)**2))
  return points</code>

Comment: @Pawe Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to do now. I don't remember there being any mention of accounting for the Value-column in your original question. Please edit the question to accurately reflect what you want to do, especially important to update the example output. Also read up on how to use the markdown syntax on stackoverflow. You highlight code with backticks `\``, not `<code>` tags.

Comment: ,okay, lets say i have 3 rows , with 3 columns (x,y is a position)
`x, y, value,
10,10, 120,
11,11,110,
24,14,98,` 
and i want to delete points with radius ,lets say =2, but in same time deleting those rows in this radius with lowest values.
result:
`x,y,value,
10,10,120,
24,14,98`
/thank You for help, and sorry i cant write this table line by line in this comment;/

Comment: @Pawe Sorry, but I still don't think I understand fully. I updated the answer, try the new instructions above.

Comment: hi, i have checked this but dont gives me result as i want to, i have updated my question, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

@cheflo , Hello again. code is working corretly but right now i had to prepared my new dataset and right now its looking like that:

```
x , y ,value
1 , 1 , 12
2 , 2 , 12
4 , 3 , 12
x , y ,value
1 , 1 , 11
2 , 2 , 11
4 , 3 , 11
x , y ,value
1 , 1 , 33
2 , 2 , 33
4 , 3 , 33
```

I have created this dataset like this one to filter by radius only equal 'values', and i need now to leave all in my radius (=1 in this example)
in OUTPUT i need :

```
x , y ,value
1 , 1 , 12
2 , 2 , 12
x , y ,value
1 , 1 , 11
2 , 2 , 11
x , y ,value
1 , 1 , 33
2 , 2 , 33
```

of course i also have normal dataset with all those values and with only one header but in this form i think would be much easier, but i have received an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'apply'
line 93, in <module>
leave_it = df.apply(distance_between, axis=1)
```

from last code right now i changed only

```
x_dist = abs(df['y'] + row['y']) <= 1 #- to +
y_dist = abs(df['x'] + row['x']) <= 1
```

What do You think?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Pawe, Please ask this as a new question, since it is a new problem. StackOverflow tries to have one specific question and the answer to that question, rather than a follow up of all the issues that occur on the progress towards a bigger more complex problem. Remember to state you problem clearly in the new question and feel free to put a link here and I will try to answer it. But be clear of exactly what you have done, so that others can answer too.

Comment: @cheflo, ok sorry. there is another topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42997271/leaving-rows-with-a-giving-value-in-column-python
Thanks!